# Set a variable to true 2 seconds after the last time "G" has been pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery

Title says it all, I know a pretty stupid way to solve this via Javascript but I wonder... if there is a smarter way? There probably is. A user can press "G" as much as he wants and this calls the function **g_pressed();**. Solutions in jquery are also fine.

Here's my solution:

```
var allowed = false;
var allowed_key = 0;

function g_pressed(){
    allowed = false;
    allowed_key++;
    setTimeout('allowed_check('+allowed_key+');', 2000);
}

function allowed_check(key){
    if(key==allowed_key){
        allowed = true;
    }
}
```

---

As you can see, it is painfully 12 lines long.

Comment: You should never use strings with `setTimeout()`. Thats evil! Use proper closures instead of relying on `eval()`.

Comment: hard to make sense of what `allowed_key` is supposed to be for. Explanation only suggests `if "G"` pressed, no limits mentioned

Comment: @charlietfl it's just a dummy function. "g_pressed();" gets triggered only if "G" is pressed anyway.

Comment: @elusive Okay! Sorry.

Comment: would make sense to just pass the keyCode into function and test it there, and setTimeout if it is keycode for "G", rather than a special function just for `G`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to store the `Timeout` in a variable and `clear` it when `g_pressed()` fires:

```
var myTimeout;
function g_pressed(){
    clearTimeout(myTimeout);
    allowed = false;
    allowed_key++;
    myTimeout = setTimeout('allowed_check', 2000, allowed_key);
}
```

Comment: This gives me an idea. Could you please review my answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/15721988/1032391

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send parameters, you need to do an anonymous function:

```
var allowed = false;
var allowed_key = 0;
function g_pressed(){
allowed = false;
allowed_key++;
setTimeout(function(allowed_key){
if(key==allowed_key){
    allowed = true;
}, 2000);
}
```